# Android image magick

Tags: android, image-processing, imagemagick

i am using image magic in my project, i get it from this https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick , after editing some code from this. when i compile this i am getting this error

> 02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

here final MagickImage img = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo("/sdcard/image.jpeg")); and this

> 02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library android-magick not found
>   : init
>   here System.loadLibrary("android-magick"); i am new to this please help me..

this is the logcat

> 02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at magick.AndroidMagickActivity.onCreate(AndroidMagickActivity.java:44)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library android-magick not found
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at magick.Magick.(Magick.java:41)
>   02-27 11:37:05.329: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  ... 14 more

Comment: got the same problem. Does anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 11):

Hey this is a common problem for Beginners. The library uses some of the Native methods.Follow the below steps

1. Download the library below link
   https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick
2. Copy the contents of the libs folder of the downloaded library to
   your libs folder
3. Copy the Folders "magick" and "fakeawt" to your projects src folder.

thats it now enjoy using it :)

Comment: i have tested using png,jpeg.

Comment: @AbhimaanMadhav The png image gave me `ImageMagicKException`, are you sure it work?

Comment: @AbhimaanMadhav how to convert png/jpeg to postscript use android-image-magick ? I can't fond any method for converting to postscript(image-magick for linux PC can do it).

Answer (score 3):

i've just ported ImageMagick on android, this time with all CPU architectures, if they don't suit you. Rebuild with ndk-build simple.
All here https://github.com/tapaulo/Android-ImageMagick

Comment: I've researched for two days already, but I can't understand how to create gif from set of jpegs with your wrapper over console commands in android. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this project : https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick

It work!