# ImageMagick for android...Program Crashing

Tags: android, imagemagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android image magick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460764/android-image-magick)

The following line causes the ImageMagic project....(https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick/tree/master/src)
System.loadLibrary("android-magick");
If anyone has used the library before,please let me know whether you have encountered the above error...
Thanking you in advance for your valuable advice